Momentary push button switch to mute an alarm buzzer
I'm working on a circuit that needs to trigger an alarm buzzer (external dry contact trigger).
It should have a facility to mute the buzzer while the alarm is still on  and turn it off when the external trigger is off.
Any suggestions how to do this?

use a microcontroller

Please provide a schematic of what you have so far

Can this circuit be easily done in solid state (transistors and FETs)? I've Googled without success, and my attempts to dream up a circuit aren't successful. I'd like to see under 3-4 discreet semiconductor items and a half dozen resistors, otherwise a relay is a more logical solution. A relay is super simple, but a semiconductor solution would be lower power and possibly smaller.

An electromagnetic relay 'K1' and a momentary push button switch 'S1' is all that is required.

When the 'alarm' dry contact closes, the lamp and the buzzer are switched on.
When the momentary push button switch is actuated, the relay 'K1' latches to switch off the buzzer.
The relay 'K1' is reset when the alarm is reset and the dry contact opens.
